# Distance of perturbed flow from the unperturbed stable manifold

Tags: dynamical-systems, perturbation-theory, nonlinear-dynamics

Consider the following system

$ \dot x= v\\
\dot v= x - x^2(1+\varepsilon cost)$

Let $\phi_\varepsilon(x,v)=\psi_\varepsilon ^{2\pi}(x,v)$ the flow of system with initial condition $(x,v)$ at time $2\pi$. So we have a discrete map.

Defining the unstable manifold as

$$W_\varepsilon^{(unstable)}=\big\{  (x,v)\in R^2 : \phi^k_\varepsilon(x,v) \rightarrow 0 \,\,for \,\,k\rightarrow-\infty \big\}$$

In the same way one can define the stable manifold.

The origin is an equilibrium point for the system, even if $\varepsilon \neq 0 $.

Consider the unperturbed unstable manifold, that is $W_0^{(unstable)}$ (which coincide with stable manifold $ W_0^{(stable)}$).

Now my book says the following:

"By continuity of the ﬂow with respect to the parameter $\varepsilon$ we have $\phi^k_\varepsilon(x,v)$ close to the unperturbed unstable manifold for $0 ≤ k ≤ K$ , for some large $K$ , e.g., the distance is $O(\varepsilon^{1/2}) $ for $K \simeq \varepsilon^{−1/2}$ "

My question is:

Why the continuity can imply this property of distance of perturbed flow from the unperturbed manifold?
How can i see this?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to also use the smooth dependence on the perturbation parameter, just the continuous dependence is not sufficient for that claim.

Then the distance between perturbed and non-perturbed solutions grows in the first order like $εt$, so that at $t=2K\pi\sim ε^{-1/2}$ the distance is still small like $ε^{1/2}$. One could have also used $K\sim ε^{-2/3}$ to get a distance $\simε^{1/3}$ and so on.

---

Let $u$ be the $ε=0$ solution and $x$ the perturbation (vector) solution with the same initial condition. Then
$$
d(t)=|x(t)-u(t)|\le \int_0^t(|f(u(s))-f(x(s))|+ε|g(s,x(s))|)\,ds
$$
Now it should be intuitive that both solutions are bounded, $x$ at or close to the equilibrium is periodic, $u$ can not move away very fast. This means that $|g(t,x(t))|\le M$ and that there is a Lipschitz constant $L$ for $f$ so that in total
$$
d(t)\le\int_0^t(Ld(s)+εM)ds
$$
which is a typical Grönwall situation leading to
$$
d(t)\le εM\frac{e^{Lt}-1}{L}
$$
This is then an a-posteriori confirmation that $x$ can not explode away from $u$.

This now somewhat defeats the first argument, as now one needs $t\sim-\frac1{2L}\lnε$ which is much smaller than $ε^{-1/2}$.

Comment: Thank you @Lutz Lehmann, but how do you conclude that "the distance between perturbed and non-perturbed solutions grows in the first order like $\varepsilon t$" ? I think that this is actually my problem, i can't see this fact. And what will happen if the distance grows in the second order like $\varepsilon^2 t$ ?

Comment: You mean that the first order perturbation term averages out to zero, so that growth in $t$ only happens from the second term on? Then just replace $ε$ with $ε^2$ in those size estimates.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand where I can "read" the fact "distance between perturbed and non-perturbed solutions grows in the first order like $\varepsilon t$". Where is this information?  Maybe in the equation for $v$ :  $\dot v = x - x^2( 1 + \varepsilon cos t ) $ ? 
About your edit in the answer: what is the function $f$? And $g$?

Comment: Your system has the form $\pmatrix{x_1'\\x_2'}=\pmatrix{x_2\\x_1-x_1^2}-ε\cos(t)\pmatrix{0\\x_1^2}$, from where I take $f$ and $g$. I'll correct that $g$ depends on $t$, which changes nothing on its boundedness. The constants can be taken as $L=2+2r_1$ and $M=r_1^2$ where $r_1$ is a bound on $x_1$.

Comment: So if the equation of $v$ was $\dot v = f + \varepsilon ^2  g$ I have the distance between perturbed and non-perturbed solutions grows like $\varepsilon^2 t$, right?

Comment: Yes, as upper bound. The actual growth may be much smaller.